# Express.js req.body undefined/defined randomly

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

trying to figure out this issue where sometimes the req.body is undefined, and then I can run it again minutes later and then there will be data.

any help will be appreciated

index.js

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const LogRequests = require('./logger.js');
const query = require('./querys.js');

const hostname = '192.168.25.48';
const port = 5050;

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(LogRequests);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

app.get('/clients', (req, res) => {
  query.selectAllClients(req, res);
});
```

query.js

```
module.exports = { selectAllClients };

async function selectAllClients(req, res) {
    try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "user",
        password: "password",
        connectString: "192.168.3.5:1521/jtv"
      });
      result = await connection.execute(`SELECT client_code, client_name FROM clients where active_ind='YES'`);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.send(err.message);
    } finally {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          await connection.close();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
      }
      if (result.rows.length == 0) {
        return res.send({ rows: 0 });
      } else {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        var JSONresult = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        return res.status(200).send(JSONresult);
      }
    }
  }
```

I can confirm the json displayed is valid, but when I check the logs I see this

```
{
  "time": "2023/04/22 18:47:50",
  "host": "192.168.25.48",
  "ip": "192.168.25.197",
  "originalUrl": "/clients",
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/clients",
  "url": "/clients",
  "body": {},
  "params": {},
  "query": {},
  "response": {
    "body": ""
  }
}
```

minutes later I can run it again and get an body

```
{
    "time": "2023/04/22 18:47:38",
    "host": "192.168.25.48",
    "ip": "192.168.25.197",
    "originalUrl": "/clients",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/clients",
    "url": "/clients",
    "body": {},
    "params": {},
    "query": {},
    "response": {
        "body": "[{\"CLIENT_CODE\":\"DEFAULT\",\"CLIENT_NAME\":\"1 - Default Pricing\"},{\"CLIENT_CODE\":\"INTERNAL\",\"CLIENT_NAME\":\"Internal Client\"}]"
    }
}
```

Comment: `req.body` does not appear in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you cant expect to run res.send multiple times.

if you fall in the first catch it will call res.send, then continue in the finally block, and res.send again and crash the server.